# Recursion in java with weighted graph checking duplicate visits

Tags: java, recursion, logic

I need to solve a problem given a weighted graph in the format of inputs containing two letters and a number: 'AC2' for example. This implies that there is a direct route from town A to town C with distance 2. I am trying to solve the problem of finding all the different routes from town C to C, given the input:
AB5, BC4, CD8, DC8, DE6, AD5, CE2, EB3, AE7

My algorithm seems to only check single routes and not taking a route multiple times as long as it is less than 30 in distance, which means it will be: CDC, CEBC, CEBCDC, CDCEBC, CDEBC, CEBCEBC, CEBCEBCEBC.

How can I change my algorithm to apply to all routes, including duplicates, as long as the distance is less than 30.

My algorithm is:

```
public int differentRoutes(char currentTown, char endTown, int maxDistance, int distance,
            int step) {
        if (distance >= maxDistance) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (currentTown == endTown && step != 0) {
            return 1;
        }

        int count = 0;
        for (char neighbor : graph.get(currentTown).keySet()) {
            distance += graph.get(currentTown).get(neighbor);
            count += differentRoutes(neighbor, endTown, maxDistance, distance, step + 1);
        }
        return count;
    }
```